# Python QTableWidget color of index and row with stylesheet

Tags: python, qt-designer

ist it possible to change the color of row and index in a Qtable widget via stylesheet in QT Designer???

[image]

```
    background-image: url(:/newPrefix/buttoooo.png);
QTableWidget{background-color: #e49e00;font: 75 12pt "Rockwell"}
QTableWidget:item:hover{ background-color: #fee103 }
QTableWidget:item:pressed{ background-color: #ff0000 }
QHeaderView{
Background-color:#e49e00;border-radius:15px;}
```

Comment: Nobody knows an answer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long long search i found a solution for stylesheet:

´´´

```
QHeaderView::section:horizontal
{
    border-top: 0px solid #fffff8;
font: 75 14pt "MS Shell Dlg 2";
}

QHeaderView::section:vertical
{
    border-left: 0px solid #fffff8;
font: 75 14pt "MS Shell Dlg 2";
}
```

´´´